# Refresh Fragment from list Adapter after delete list item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

How to refresh fragment list after deleted item on list adapter ?

Here is my code for the adapter:
https://pastebin.com/rGhV3fXj

```
builder.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            if(pos!=1){
                                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM BmiPersons where id = "+pos );
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Delete Success !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                  ListDataAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You Can't delete initial data. ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

And here is my fragment's code:
https://pastebin.com/hcPDKtVA

```
public void updatePersonList(){
    mBmiList.clear();
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = dbHelper.getBmiInformation();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            list_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID));
            list_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DATE));
            list_age = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_AGE));
            list_result = Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RESULT)));

            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(list_id,list_date,list_age,list_result);
            mBmiList.add(dataProvider);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must delete data from `mBmiList`, which is used in `mListDataAdapter`, then call `mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: which files should I change? fragment or adapter

Comment: List which used to bind adapter. Value must removed from that list too

Comment: can you please put mListDataAdapter too.?

Comment: list which you used in mListDataAdapter from that too you should delete item

Comment: sorry, I have successfully removed the item, but the fragment does not refresh.